# Как  открыть html без полного пути?

Tags: html, delphi-7

Есть веб-браузер на форме, в которой нужно открыть файл html, но он открывается, только если прописывать весь путь.  Можно как-то  сделать, чтоб не писать путь?

```
wb1.navigate('D:\project\1.html');
а надо что-то типа:
wb1.navigate('1.html');
```

Файл лежит в папке с проектом, но все равно не открывается.

Comment: @hndgrbfv, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

```
wb1.navigate(ExpandFileName('1.html'));
```

Все намного проще. Иногда полезно в справку заглядывать. В uses добавьте модуль `SysUtils`.

Answer (score 2):

Можно написать вспомогательную процедуру, типа:

```
Procedure OpenLocalWEB(File:String='1.html');
begin
  wb1.navigate(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + File');
end;
```

Использовать так:

```
   procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      OpenLocalWEB('1.html');
    end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Определите переменную, содержащую путь от корня (d:\project1) и объединяйте ее с 1.html

Вызов будет типа `wb1.navigate(path_var + '1.html');` извините за синтаксис, не помню как делается конкатенация строк в Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

Если я ничего не путаю, существует файл конфигурации, где можно задать базовую директорию. Пропишите в нем соответствующую директорию, и будет все работать.

Answer (score 0):

`Wb1.navigate(str+'\1 htm');`  с `htm` или `html` сами смотрите как он у вас сохраняет в полном формате или нет.

Answer (score -1):

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(GetCurrentDir+ '/1.mht');
```

Главное чтобы док лежал с проектом в одной папке